# Stream single application from macOS to Linux using X11 forwarding or similar

Tags: linux, x11, macos, vnc

I want to stream an application (preferably with the menu bar on top) from macOS to Linux. You can do this in the other direction, from Linux to macOS, via XQuartz and X11 forwarding.

I have seen people say this is possible with VNC but without any specific solutions. Is there a suitable method to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

MacOS does not use X11 displays for applications. It instead uses [Quartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_(graphics_layer)) as it's graphics layer. There is nothing built into Quartz similar to X11's feature to forward displays over a network so I do not believe you will be able to stream a single application in the fashion that you'd like.

[Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleRemoteDesktop) for connecting to Apple Remote Desktop should help.

On the Mac:

1. Open System Preferences (it's in the Apple menu)
2. Open the Sharing panel
3. Open the box Apple Remote Desktop
4. Click Access Privileges
5. Check the box VNC viewers may control screen with password, and enter a password
6. Click OK

On Ubuntu:

1. Launch Remmina Remote Desktop Client
2. Select Connection > New from menu
3. Select VNC - Virtual Network Computing as Protocol
4. Fill Server field with either IP address or hostname of the Mac
5. Optionally fill both User name and Password to make Remmina remember Your credentials
6. IMPORTANT: Set Color depth to High color (15 bit) or better, otherwise connection will fail
7. Click Connect (or Save to reuse it later)

The process for a non-ubuntu distro would be similar, but instead of using steps 1-3 you would just use whatever vncviewer software that comes with your distro or install an alternative (I've personally always just used the vncviewer that comes with tigervnc).